# How does the boost::bind work with std::greater and std::less_equal

Tags: c++, boost, stl

The following code is designed to count the number of elements that satisfy the following condition:

```
(i > 5) && (i <=10)

std::vector<int> ints;
..
int count=std::count_if(
  ints.begin(),
  ints.end(),
  boost::bind( // # bind 1
    std::logical_and<bool>(),
    boost::bind(std::greater<int>(),_1,5), // # bind 2
    boost::bind(std::less_equal<int>(),_1,10))); // # bind 3

template <class T> struct greater : binary_function <T,T,bool> {
  bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const
    {return x>y;}
};
```

I decompose the above statement as follows:

`boost::bind(std::greater<int>(),_1,5)` is used for `i > 5`

`boost::bind(std::less_equal<int>(),_1,10)` is used for `i <=10`.

The problem I have is how to understand the above code because if I wrote the code and I will write the following:

`boost::bind(std::greater<int>(),_2,5)` is used for `i > 5`
`boost::bind(std::less_equal<int>(),_2,10)` is used for `i <=10`.

The function `std::greater` needs two parameters (i.e. `x` and `y`) and makes sure that `x > y`. So I thought we need to bind `y` with `5` so that we can find all `Xs`. Of course, my thought is wrong.

Can someone explain for me?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placeholders `_1`, `_2`, etc. designate the parameters of the functor the specific (inner-most) `bind` call returns, not for the full expression you might be building. I.e. for:

```
boost::bind(std::greater<int>(),_1,5)
```

... the `bind` returns a functor that passes the first parameter it receives as the first argument to the `greater<int>` functor.

Comment: It seems that the **# bind 1** provides `_1` to **# bind 2** and **# bind 2** returns a bool to `std::logical_and`. In turn, the `_1` and `5` are given into the functor `std::greater<int>()` as the first and second parameters.

Comment: so you mean `_1` is the first parameter that **#bind 1** receives and it passes it to the **# bind 2** as the first parameter to functor `greater<int>`.

Comment: @q0987: Sorry, i guess the previous comment was misleading: Nested bind calls are resolved from inner-most to outer-most. So the expression `bind(and, bind(greater,_1,5), bind(less_equal,_1,10))` when called with `x` becomes `bind(and, greater(x,5), less_equal(x,10))`, ... etc.